# Why doesn't this Event Listener work when I edit the HTML with JS?

Tags: javascript, events, event-listener

here's some example code to illustrate what im trying to do

```
    <div id="thing">No</div>
    <script>
        let elt = document.getElementById("thing")
        elt.addEventListener("click", () => elt.innerHTML = "Yes");
        elt.addEventListener("change", () => alert("Running"));
    </script>
```

I want the second Event Listener to run the callback function when the html of the element is edited

Comment: You can take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)

Comment: basically the change event fires up in input elements when the user changes the value inside them, that's quite different from your case here when you're changing the inner html of the div programtically when the user clicks.

Comment: thanks that clarifies it